# Is there a way to use an Android tablet as a wifi handsfree device?

Tags: wi-fi, audio, hands-free

My situation:

- Android (4.0.3) tab hooked up to my car stereo using the headphones connector.
- Android (2.3.5) phone (HTC Desire HD), which I use to call, text, browse, etc.

Since my car stereo's Bluetooth device died I thought I could use the Android tab as a audio relay device. Problem is: the tab has no Bluetooth. It has wifi though.

Is there any way to use an Android device as a handsfree adapter over wifi? Some kind of wifi relay between the phone and the tablet, perhaps?

Comment: Am I right that you basically want to make phone calls from you tablet that are relayed to you smartphone?

Comment: I think he wants to connect to the tablet using Wi-Fi, and control the tablet (music choice, volume, etc) as if it were the bluetooth head-end of a stereo. So the tablet plays the music, but the phone controls the tablet's audio.

Comment: no. both wrong. I want to make a phone call with my phone, but in my country it is illegal to hold your phone at ear height. That is why I had a car stereo with bluetooth, so I can hear the person I am talking to over my car speakers.

Comment: EDIT: I need to replace that function and I already have a tab in my car directly connected to my stereo. I want my outgoing audio from my phone over wifi to my tab. phone-> wifi -> tab -> cable -> car stereo. If I can dial from my tab that would be an extra.

Answer (score 0):

Does the tab has USB port. How about adding an external custom BT device. BT device talks to android app on tab via any serial library for example scm (http://www.embeddedunveiled.com/scm-wiki).